# How to test database views using Entity Framework Core's in memory DB provider?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I tried to add objects to views, it throws exception saying `unable to track an instance of type because it is a query type`. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Query Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) are *read-only* by definition (for *all* database providers, not only for in memory):

> - Are never tracked for changes on the DbContext and therefore are never inserted, updated or deleted on the database.

However, additionally to their usual usage scenarios of

> - Mapping to database views.
> - Mapping to tables that do not have a primary key defined.

they allow

> - Mapping to queries defined in the model.

or in other words

> - May be mapped to a *defining query* - A defining query is a secondary query declared in the model that acts a data source for a query type.

which is achieved with [ToQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.querytypebuilder-1.toquery?view=efcore-2.1) fluent API:

> Configures a query used to provide data for a query type.

So for testing query types with in memory database, you should utilize the *defining query* mapping capability.

For instance, inside `OnModelCreating` override you could add something like this:

```
if (Database.IsInMemory())
{
   // In memory test query type mappings
    modelBuilder.Query<MyQueryType>().ToQuery(() => LINQ_query);
    // ... similar for other query types
}
else
{
    // Database query type mappings
    modelBuilder.Query<MyQueryType>().ToView("MyQueryTypeView");
    // ... 
}
```

where `LINQ_query` is a normal LINQ query accessing context `DbSet`s and `DbQuery`s and  projecting to `MyQueryType`.

Then the test would feed the involved entities with data and the queries using `DbQuery`s will retrieve the data from the defining query.

---

The above should be the recommended way to test views with in memory database.

Just for completeness, it's possible to directly feed the `DbQuery`s with data (basically mocking them) by creating some sort of query repository, but with the following restriction - it must be *shared* (`static`), because currently EF Core does not handle correctly db context members (like global query filter does) other than `DbSet<T>` and `DbQuery<T>`.

Something like this:

```
public static class FakeQueryProvider
{
    static Dictionary<Type, IQueryable> queries = new Dictionary<Type, IQueryable>();

    public static void SetQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        lock (queries)
            queries[typeof(T)] = query;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> GetQuery<T>()
    {
        lock (queries)
            return queries.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var query) ? (IQueryable<T>)query : Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
    }

    public static QueryTypeBuilder<T> ToFakeQuery<T>(this QueryTypeBuilder<T> builder)
        where T : class
    { 
        return builder.ToQuery(() => GetQuery<T>());
    }
}
```

then instead of

```
.ToQuery(() => LINQ_query);
```

you would use

```
.ToFakeQuery();
```

and would feed it inside the test like this

```
 List<MyQueryType> data = ...;
 FakeQueryProvider.SetQuery(data.AsQueryable());
```

Still I recommend the first approach due to shared storage limiting the ability to run `MyQueryType` related tests in parallel.

Comment: Include extension method [is not supported for entities with defining query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.corestrings.includeonentitywithdefiningquerynotsupported?view=efcore-3.1), so, in that case, the test will fail.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva Too bad - yet another limitation :( Btw, they are considering removing InMemory provider at all in the (near) future, so the whole topic might become no sense. Probably the people should go with [Testing with in-memory SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/SQLite) or similar.

Comment: `modelBuilder.Query<MyQueryType>()` is obsolete. Use `modelBuilder.Entity<MyQueryType>().HasNoKey()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up refactoring Ivan's extension class code based on his suggestions/recommendations, as follows.  I added overloads to the ToFakeQuery method to take in a dictionary.

```
public static class InMemoryQueryProviderExtensions
{
    static Dictionary<Type, IQueryable> queries = new Dictionary<Type, IQueryable>();

    public static void SetQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        lock (queries)
            queries[typeof(T)] = query;
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> GetQuery<T>()
    {
        lock (queries)
            return queries.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var query) ? (IQueryable<T>)query : Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
    }
    private static IQueryable<T> GetQuery<T>(Dictionary<Type, IQueryable> queryDictionary)
    {
        return queryDictionary.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var query) ? (IQueryable<T>)query : Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
    }

    public static QueryTypeBuilder<T> ToFakeQuery<T>(this QueryTypeBuilder<T> builder)
        where T : class
    {
        return builder.ToQuery(() => GetQuery<T>());
    }
    public static QueryTypeBuilder<T> ToFakeQuery<T>(this QueryTypeBuilder<T> builder, Dictionary<Type, IQueryable> queryDictionary)
        where T : class
    {
        return builder.ToQuery(() => GetQuery<T>(queryDictionary));
    }
}
```

And then, creating a new derived class for my DBContext as follows.  Basically, making the derived instance of the in-memory DBContext maintain the dictionary.

```
public class TlInMemoryDbContext : TlDbContext
{
    public TlInMemoryDbContext(DbContextOptions<TlDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    Dictionary<Type, IQueryable> queries = new Dictionary<Type, IQueryable>();
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Query<EffectiveTimeEntry>().ToFakeQuery(queries);
    }

    public void SetQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        lock (queries)
            queries[typeof(T)] = query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the above as suggested by Ivan Stoev.

This is how it looked

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  if(Database.IsSqlServer())
  {
     modelBuilder.Query<ProviderRating>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.ToView("vGetProviderRatingData", "dbo");
                    entity.Property(e => e.col1)
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
                    entity.Property(e => e.col2)
                    .HasMaxLength(60)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
                    entity.Property(e => e.col3)
                    .HasMaxLength(10)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                });
  }
  else
  {
    modelBuilder.Query<ProviderRating>().ToQuery(() =>
                 ProviderRatingFake.Select(m => new ProviderRating()
                 {
                     col1 = m.col1,
                     col2 = m.col2,
                     col3 = m.col3,
                 }
                ));
  }
}
```

The `ProviderRatingFake` class exactly similar to `ProviderRating` class

I also added this code in DbContext file (`ProviderQualityContext`)

```
 public virtual DbSet<ProviderRatingFake> ProviderRatingFake { get; set; }

 public virtual DbQuery<ProviderRating> ProviderRating { get; set; }
```

Then I tested like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestingWithInMemoryDb()
{
   var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ProviderQualityContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Read_From_Database")
                .Options;
  var fakeProviderRating = new ProviderRatingFake
            {
                col1 = 1,
                col2 = "Something",
                col3 = "Something",
            };
  using (var context = new ProviderQualityContext(options))
  {
    context.ProviderRatingFake.Add(fakeProviderRating);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }

  //use the newly created context and inject it into controller or repository
  using (var context = new ProviderQualityContext(options))
  {
    //use the test context here and make assertions that you are returning the
   //fake data
   //Note that the actual code uses the Query like this
   //This query will be populated with fake data using the else block
   //in the method OnModelCreating
   var returnedData = this.dbContext.Query<ProviderRating>().Where(m => m.col1 == 
   "Something")
  }

}
```